# How to fetch distinct existing key in all document of a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have below userRole collection, in which found distinct keys of associatePermission object from this collection, in a single object..

e.g. if I pass 2 or 3 roles in this object or for all roles want to union all permission of these roles in a single object.

```
"userRole":{
"_id" : ObjectId("58902f6b5d474004b4034026"),
"roleName" : "Filler",
"permission" : {
    "ActionPermissions" : {
        "Incidence Management" : {
            "Trouble Ticketing" : {
                "Add Ticket" : {}
            }
        }
    }
},
"associatePermission" : {
    "ActionPermissions" : {
        "Incidence Management" : {
            "Trouble Ticketing" : {
                "Add Ticket" : {},
                "Bulk Closure" : true
            },
            "Ageing Report" : {
                "Filter Report" : true
            }
        },
        "Preventive Maintenance" : {
            "Edit Ticket" : {
                "Severity" : true
            }
        }
    },
    "DataPermissions" : {
        "Incidence Management" : {
            "Trouble Ticketing" : {
                "Add Ticket" : {}
            }
        }
    }
 }
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58902f6b5d474556565"),
    "roleName" : "Filler",
    "permission" : {
        "ActionPermissions" : {
            "Incidence Management" : {
                "Trouble Ticketing" : {
                    "Add Ticket" : {}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "associatePermission" : {
        "ActionPermissions" : {
            "Incidence Management" : {
                "Trouble Ticketing" : {
                    "Add Ticket" : {},
                    "Bulk Closure" : true
                },
                "Ageing Report" : {
                    "Filter Report" : true
                }
            },
            "Preventive Maintenance" : {
                "Edit Ticket" : {true}
            }
        },
        "DataPermissions" : {
            "Incidence Management" : {
                "Trouble Ticketing" : {
                    "Add Ticket" : {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a sample output you want. and have you tried any query by yourself?

Comment: yes i have tried lots of $distinct and $setunion related query regarding this  as per sample output , you can see in above collection have two records exists in both document "associatePermission" property is common , want to union simply.. tried queries..  [http://jsbin.com/zuxuzupoco/edit?html,js,console]                                      above shared link have a distinct query but it returning different object for all document and i want to club(union) all permission in a single object fron this userRole colllection

Comment: I am not able to see, sample  output, please mention sample output in your question detail

Comment: @PuneetSingh, sample output [http://jsbin.com/zuxuzupoco/edit?html,js,console]